# Execution order with nested event handlers

Tags: javascript, event-loop, order-of-execution

Check this simple example:

```js
function doit() {
  const button = document.querySelector('button');

  button.addEventListener('click', (e) => {
    dispatchFoo();
    console.log('click listener executed');
  })
  
  document.addEventListener('foo', handleFoo);

  button.click();

  console.log('end reached')
}

function handleFoo() {
  console.log('foo listener executed');
}

function dispatchFoo() {
  const event = new CustomEvent('foo');
  document.dispatchEvent(event);
}

console.clear();
doit();
```

```html
<button>button</button>
```

This outputs (as I expected):

```
foo listener executed
click listener executed
end reached
```

Can I rely on this execution order?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, [`EventTarget.dispatchEvent()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/dispatchEvent) dispatches the event synchronously.